# In Blender 3.2, can I exclude light sources form a shadow catcher without compositing view layers?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadowcatcher

My scene has an object which is lit from the side by a light. There is another light on top of the object, and a shadow catcher underneath the object. I want the object to be lit by the side light, but I only want to catch the shadow from the top light. In the past I have achieved this using a second "shadow" view layer and composition.

I'm wondering if Blender 3.2 now has an option to exclude specific light sources from a shadow catcher? I see that there is a light group option but I'm not sure it would allow me to do that.